# Oracle Endeca (Commerce) forge error : Failed to create the directory C:: Permission denied at -e line 1

Tags: oracle, endeca, baseline, oracle-commerce, endeca-workbench

When trying to run baseline update in Oracle Commerce 11.3.0 I get the following error :

```
Failed to create the directory C:: Permission denied at -e line 1.
```

in the mkpath_repository log in endeca Platform services.The component Forge fails without any logs in the directory `.\logs\forges\Forge` . I have run by both endeca user as well as administrator which are both the owner of [`appdir`]. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved this yet, from your error message it sounds like it's trying to create the C directory. When the error message presents itself it should print out the path of the directory it's trying to create.

Example from Oracle Support: "Failed to remove directory D:\Endeca\apps\\config\script.....\data\complete_index_config: Permission denied at -e line 1."

Sounds like you might have a variable configured incorrectly somewhere.

Comment: Check your environment variables. So 'echo $ENDECA_ROOT' for linux, or 'echo %ENDECA_ROOT%' for windows. Endeca also sets some environment variables again in the set_environment.sh file which is called from the runcommand.sh file in linux.

If none of those appear to be incorrect, try to run the baseline outside of your application using the script file(baseline_update.sh for linux) or ensure you're starting your processes from the correct directory. In the migration process there were several relative paths, so running the start scripts from your C: directory could affect your output.

Comment: echo %ENDECA_ROOT% give me the correct location : C:\Endeca\PlatformServices\11.1.0 .
I am running it from the D: drive and tried to run baseline update using the script file as well. But the error persists. I think it is related to endeca in windows.

Comment: I don't believe that Platform Services 11.1 is compatible with Oracle Commerce 11.3. Please refer to the purpose and details section of the [Oracle Compatibility Matrix](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=302071565132441&parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1555914.1&id=1530353.1)

Comment: I'm not positive this will solve your issue if no other errors are getting displayed. It depends on where in the indexing process it is failing, and I am unfamiliar with the windows installation as well as applications still using Forge. I wish I could be more help, there are logging levels you can change in each component that might give you some more information as well.

Comment: Ohh .. thanks a tonneaue. I'll install it on fresh copy of windows and update here. Thank you so much for your valuable comments and time .